# how to register a facebook user in android app if the user logged in through phone number?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

i am creating an android app that can register a user through social networking sites like gmail, Facebook and twitter. Now if a user logged in through his/her email id then i can register him through his email id, but if a user is logging in through phone number, and he hasn't provided any email id in Facebook, so how can i get any verified data like phone number or email id as Facebook does not gives its user phone number [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) and user hasn't provided any email id in Facebook (he has logged in via phone number)

**Edit**
[this is what i've tried so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLbeV.jpg)
here i use to login a user though phone number and that user is not so frequent actually so the only few details i get so far

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the phone number of a Facebook user via the Graph API. Even not if the user set it to **public**.

Comment: i know sir, then how the other apps like instagram register user who log in through facebook using the phone number, i mean how they authorize him/her for posting anything

Comment: they are use *email* or *phone_number* for login.. not compullsurry EMAIL.. :)

Comment: you didn't get my point. A user who is not logging in through email, he is logging in through phone number so how instagram can say that an authorized user is trying to log in as the email id is not available and phone number is not provided by facebook

Comment: into the FACEBOOK response you can check the EMAIL and Phone number.. depending on it.. you can add your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in from Facebook in your app you can place an Edit text which would already be half filled with the information provided by Facebook and then you can ask the user to fill the empty required fields it could also act as final confirmation of the user info and then proceed further.

Thanks

Comment: Suppose a user logged in and i present him a form having 4 feilds, UserName, Date of Birth, Email Phone No. Now, UserName and Date of Birth can be retrieve from facebook and email and phone number he has to enter to submit, but user name and date of birth are not verified details anyone can enter any birthdate or username in facebook. All i am asking, is there any varified detail(other than email, phone no) of a user can be retrieve from facebook, on basis of that i can authorize him for using my app

Comment: <EditText ...
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</EditText>

Comment: Those fields which are already filled you can set them as
     
<EditText ... android:clickable="false" android:cursorVisible="false" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"> </EditText>

Comment: and what would that do?